# Подсчитать количество записей за 2018 год SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Всем привет, столкнулся с маленькой проблемой. Есть связанные таблицы, данные из них я получил, но мне нужно посчитать записи за 2018 год.
Вот все данные из таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из фото:

```
SELECT *
FROM Journal
JOIN JournalRow ON Journal.JournalID = JournalRow.JournalID
JOIN BusinessService ON BusinessService.BusinessServiceID = JournalRow.BusinessServiceID
JOIN BusinessServiceGroup ON BusinessServiceGroup.BusinessServiceGroupID = BusinessService.BusinessServiceGroupID
WHERE BusinessServiceGroup.BusinessServiceGroupName = 'Шиномонтаж'

GO
```

Я пытался считать с помощью COUNT, но так как дата в полном формате, то считает лишь по одной записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужен вывод типа `2018 |  4`. Как мне это осуществить?

Comment: Какой формат поля `Journal.JournalDt`?

Comment: @СтаниславГрот datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Mysql есть [функции для работы с датами](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

[YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) одна из них, она позволяет извлечь год

В вашем случае, необходимо заменить

```sql
SELECT Journal.JournalDt AS JournalYear, COUNT(Journal.JournalDt) AS JournalCountRow
```

на

```sql
SELECT YEAR(Journal.JournalDt) AS JournalYear, COUNT(Journal.JournalDt) AS JournalCountRow
```

и

```sql
GROUP BY Journal.JournalDt
```

на

```sql
GROUP BY YEAR(Journal.JournalDt)
```

[Пример с YEAR()](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9583d8/1/0)

Comment: Простите, но как тут должна работать группировка по полю, которого в таблице нет?

Comment: @Glechik мы создали вычисляемое поле JournalYear, в котором только год, в mysql можно группировать по вычисляемому полю. Так же можно написать GROUP BY YEAR(Journal.JournalDt). Вы пробовали запустить запрос с предложенными правками?

Comment: Да, я запускал. Выдало ошибку Invalid column name 'JournalYear'.

Comment: Кстати GROUP BY YEAR(Journal.JournalDt) действительно помогло)))

Comment: @Glechik это может еще зависеть он настроек БД, например, от параметра `mode` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html